# In Python, how do I select an item in a list and then a couple of characters in that list item?

Tags: python, list, element

In Python, I am getting a requested string from an autonomous vehicle that I am splitting into a list at each , and then I need to reference a particular item in that list and then reference 2 of the 10 characters in that list item.

To reference the list item I am using [] and when I have a string by itself that I am referencing 2 of the 10 characters I am using [], so I am trying to find the syntax that will do both of these in one line.

```
test_string = '$OSI,8080FAFABF,S,1,4.5' # 50% Forward (191)
#test_string = '8080FAFA40' # 50% Reverse (64)
test_string = test_string.split(",")
print (test_string)
speed = (int(test_string[1],16)) #Problem is pulling the 'BF' from the second list item
print(speed)
if speed in range (0,128):    
    motor = ("%.1f%%" % abs((((speed-128)/128)*100)) + ' Reverse Thrust')
    print (motor)
elif speed in range (129,256):
    motor = ("%.1f%%" % (((speed-127)/128)*100) + ' Forward Thrust')
    print (motor)
elif speed == 128:
    motor = ('No Thrust')
    print(motor)
else:
    motor = ('Error')
    print(motor)
```

I expect to get the 'BF' from the second element of the list and convert that hexadecimal value to decimal value and run it through the if else set.

Comment: Why do you think `int(s,16)` should yield the last 2 characters of `s`?

Comment: Reusing the name `test_string` for something that isn't a `str` is not a great idea.

Comment: The 16 is the conversion from hexadecimal to decimal. This is just my proof of concept test code. The variable names are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

```py
test_string[1][-2:]
```

(assuming you are interested in the last two characters of the "8080FAFABF" string.

To convert the hex string to decimal you had the right idea.

```py
int(test_string[1][-2:],16)
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple like that.